# problem with load internal image in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have an object file, it contain personal information include image, the problem is i cannot load the image by using Variable, i can load image in this way:

```
<h1><img src={require('./img/osama.PNG')} class="bd-placeholder-img rounded-circle"
       height="250px" width="250px"/></h1>
```

but if i try to load it from my object like this:

```
 <h1><img src={require(Personal.img)} class="bd-placeholder-img rounded-circle"
       height="250px" width="250px"/></h1>
```

show me this errer:

```
Error: Cannot find module './img/osama.PNG'
webpackEmptyContext
G:/sportfolio/src/components sync:2
Header.render
G:/sportfolio/src/components/Header.js:13
  10 |               <div class="bg-img">
  11 | <section class="sheader text-center">
  12 |     <div class="container">
> 13 |       <h1><img src={require(Personal.img)} class="bd-placeholder-img rounded-circle"
  14 |        height="250px" width="250px"/></h1>
  15 |       <p class="lead-h lead"><b>{Personal.name}</b></p>
  16 |       <p>
View compiled
▶ 18 stack frames were collapsed.
Module../src/index.js
G:/sportfolio/src/index.js:6
  3 | import App from './App';
  4 | import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
  5 | import {BrowserRouter as Router} from "react-router-dom";
> 6 | ReactDOM.render(<Router><App /></Router>, document.getElementById('root'));
  7 | 
  8 | // If you want your app to work offline and load faster, you can change
  9 | // unregister() to register() below. Note this comes with some pitfalls.
```

if i test this

```
console.log(Personal.img)
```

is show me the exactly same image url ('./img/osama.PNG'), i don't know where is the problem

Comment: everything work well, if just i use the text instead of variable, and all information display without any problem from Personal object except img with require function...... Personal is just a very simple javascript object, nothing special

Comment: Your code seems fine, again, make a sandbox, show the full error, show the folder structure

Comment: Here, try to reproduce: https://codesandbox.io/s/q-57538792-requireimg-69nq8